# Port is closed, how am I to tell whether the cause is on my side or on my ISP side?

Tags: firewall, port, bittorrent

I want the port which my BitTorrent client works on to be open. My PC is connected directly to WAN without a router. I turned off the firewall on ISP side, but the port is still closed. I didn't explicitly install any firewall on my PC either, at least I don't recall it.

Is there any way to tell on which side the problem is?

I checked the port through the Transmission BitTorrent client itself, through online port checkers and through `nmap` on another PC connected through a separate channel.

`nmap` report is:

```
Host is up.

PORT       STATE       SERVICE

55133/tcp  filtered    unknown
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `telnet localhost 55133` on your pc, on a local terminal. If you do not connect, it's something blocking the port (or not opening at all) on your pc.

Comment: telnet localhost 55133
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

Comment: It connected, meaning the port is open, but using IPv6 ( ::1 ). So type: `telnet -4 localhost 55133` to force IPv4 connection. I suppose you've used IPv4 on your test using `nmap`.

Comment: What's your distro and version?

Comment: telnet -4 localhost 55133
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

Comment: I use ArchLinux on this PC, but the same problem is on two other PCs on Lubuntu. When all PCs were connected through a router. I temporarily disconnected the router to exclude it from possible causes.

Comment: Ok, since you connected using `telnet -4` also, the port is open and listening. You mention that you're directly connected to WAN. Is there any LAN between your computers? Next thing to try is to `telnet -4 NameOrIP 55133` from one of the other machines, if they are on the same LAN. It's the easiest way to check if any firewall blocks incoming traffic.

Comment: I've just said that I intentionally disconnected the router, so at this moment there is no other PCs on the local network. There is no local network at all.

Comment: You could still have a switch to connect all your PCs. Nevermind,  type `sudo iptables -vL` to see if any firewall rules are present. If not, it seems to me that something is blocking the port from the ISP side. Another option would be to reconnect the ISP router and enable UPnP (universal plug and play). It helps bittorrent connections but it's a bit of a security risk.

Comment: `sudo iptables -vL  Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination`

Comment: Clear, no firewall rules. Give `UPnP` a try; I suppose it'll be available somewhere in your router's options.

Comment: No firewall rules means the cause of the problem is not on my side, am I right?

Comment: Thank you, Krackout!

Comment: Some ISPs block BitTorrent, seeing it as mostly piracy, which is irritating. Possible work-arounds: https://fastestvpn.com/blog/ways-to-bypass-torrent-blocking/